# GUI's that support screenreaders?

Tags: user-interface, tkinter, accessibility, voiceover

I'm creating an application that helps to teach coding to the visually impaired. I started off with Tkinter in Python, however, I learned that TKinter does not support VoiceOver (Mac VoiceOver doesn't read the text inside the GUI).

Does anyone know a module that does support VoiceOver?

Comment: Can you explain a little about why tkinter didn't work?  It seems like they would be completely separate.  Also, are you using Python 2?  You wrote Tkinter which is the Python 2 style.

Comment: I had tkinter functions already in it. I changed "from tkinter import *" 
 to "import Tka11y as tkinter"

Answer (score 0):

First I'm a blind programmer, 
if you want your app to be accessible for every screen reader  you have to use WXpython. it's open sorce lib
https://wiki.wxpython.org/Getting%20Started#Getting_started_with_wxPython

Comment: Hi, @AhmedTheBest, maybe you could improve your answer by adding information about wxPython's support for VoiceOver. I'm guessing it does support it, since you wrote "every screen reader", but I think it would be nice, if you could write something about that specific case. A link with information to prove that wxPython supports VoiceOver would be nice, as well (or a statement that this is based on personal experience). The link you provided does not provide any information about VoiceOver support.